# Hacer ejecutable protecto en python

Tags: mysql, python, tkinter, exe, reportlab

Hola amigo tengo un proyecto contruido con python 3 en los cuales use las librerias:

**tkinter** para entorno grafico
**mysql.connector**  para la coneccion a la base de datos 
**repoertlab** para la creacion de los reportes

El cual hay varios modulo que estan ingresados en carpetas, como el de coneccion a la base de datos
esto para mantener un orden ustedes sabran.

E:\TODOPYTHON\CONTROL_CLIENTES **raiz**
│   buscar.png
│   calendario.png
│   codigo_basededatos.sql
│   Control_Caja.py
│   grupo.png
│   ingresar2.png
│   Ingreso_Cliente.py
│   interes2.png
│   modulo2.png
│   Operaciones_Mensuales.py
│   test.py
│
|
├───extenciones **subcarpeta**
 
│   │   mysqlconec.py
│   │   queries.py
│   │   reportes.py
│   
|
│

la pregunta es **COMO HACER EJECUTABLE O INSTALABLE ESTE PROGRAM**
el cual se pueda usar en cualquier computadora, que solo se ejecute o se intale, cabe mencionar que la base da datos esta en un servidor externo.

Comment: Saludos bro, espero te encuentres bien, 4 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes. 2. Revisa el tour: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y obtengas tu primera medalla. 3. Revisa cómo preguntar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 4. ¿Has probado en buscar "COMO HACER EJECUTABLE + python" en el buscador de tu preferencia? Esto último te lo digo en buen plan dado que existen ingredientes para que las preguntas sean muy bien recibidas, te invito a leerlas en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Cuando hay intento, con más ganas la comunidad ayuda :D

Answer (score 1):

tenes que instalar pyinstaller con`pip install pyinstaller` despues de instalar tenes que escribir en consola `pyinstaller --onefile elnombredelarchivo`
obviamente tenes que estar en el directorio donde se encuentra el archivo
--onefile significa que lo queres todo dentro de un archivo

https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html aca te dejo la documentacion para que veas las diferentes opciones

Answer (score 0):

Para compilar todo lo que quieres te recomiendo utilizar el `SciPy` (https://pypi.org/project/scipy/). Es muy bueno para compilar carpetas y para que integres las librerías que haz utilizado; lógicamente te recomiendo que primero crees tu entorno virtual.